# On textarea changes - ajax post

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have text area. Textarea Content arising from nestable list serealized process.
Textarea content is like: `[{"id":1,"children":[{"id":4}]},{"id":2}]`

Text area:

```
 <div class="span6">
    <h3>Serialised Output (per list)</h3>
    <textarea id="nestable_list_1_output" class="m-wrap span12"></textarea>
 </div>
```

Also i have one jquery function:

```
$(function() { 

function conv(data){
var result=[];
function dfs(node, parent) {
    for(var i in node){
        result.push({id:node[i].id,pid:parent});
        if (node[i]['children']) dfs(node[i]['children'],node[i]['id']);
    }
}
dfs(data, 0);
return result;
}
```

I want make ajax post every time when values on texarea ​​are changed.

```
var data     = JSON.stringify(conv($.parseJSON($("textarea#nestable_list_1_output").val())));

$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: "http://example.com/navigation/save_menu",
  data: 'menu_data=' + JSON.stringify(data),
  dataType: 'json',
  success: console.log('Data Post:' + data),
```

});
How to do that?
Many thanks for responses.
Karlis.

**UPDATE**

Based on great comunity members sugestions **event** has changed to **clik button**.
Thanks for sugestions ;)

Comment: Are you sure you want an ajax post every time the values change? That means every letter change will be an ajax post. Wouldn't you rather have a submit button?

Comment: Did you mean `$('textarea').on('change', function(){ // $.post(...) })` ? If yes then sounds terrible to me.

Comment: I agree with @ShadowCat7, you (Kārlis Millers) should think about it.

Comment: @ShadowCat7 Yes - submit butom is nice idea

Comment: @KārlisMillers, So i think yop got the idea of `submit` and I assumed that you don't need help on that, if you don't have any problem with `ajax` call.

Answer (score 1):

You would create a `change` event:

```
$("#nestable_list_1_output").change(function() {
    var currentText = this.value;
    //AJAX TIME
});
```

Comment: Jeah, in fiddle is working, but in live not. Firebug doesn`t show any error. Feel like text area value is empty..( In source code )

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
$("#textarea").on('keyup paste', function(e) {
    clearTimeout($(this).data('timeout'));
    $(this).data('timeout', setTimeout(function(){
        alert(e.target.value);
    }, 200));
});
```

[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/M9MrE/)

This should even work in case of copy paste from keyboard and from mouse

Comment: I can see two answers, why two ? Instead you could have edit the first one.

Comment: I deleted the previous answer, How come it is still visible?

Comment: Yes, it's been deleted but I can see because of my higher reps and it's better to keep one answer, less unnecessary content on `SO`.

Comment: Makes sense, Will take care of it next time.